# how to control particles position

Tags: particles

i am trying to emit some particles to create a logo. i have tree different emitters (red, yellow, blue) and i'm trying to determine those particles to arrive at certain locations. I tried using magnetic force and stickiness, but it doesn't seem to work. What other tools are there to control where particles go and how to make them stick to that position?

Thank you.

This is what i'm trying to achieve. i also needed the particles to bounce of the ground and then settle while respecting the 2 different areas. I kind of manage to do it using molecular addon, but i cant control the bouncing so in the end i made a mesh cage for the middle area and a cylinder cage for the outer area. 
[image]

Comment: Probably you will want to search for "Particles Curve Guide" or provide some screenshots of what exactly you want to achieve. What you have and what it should look like.

Comment: Keyed particles is probably the best solution [Keyed — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/physics/keyed.html)

Comment: thank you for your comments. i managed using meshes with collision that force the particles to keep into the shape that i need.